# What is the meaning of this answer?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I asked a following question on a support forum.

> I have a build a custom theme using Understrap and now I am selling it
>   via WordPress(free version) and ThemeForest (Paid version)....
>
> Now I saw that there is a new update for understrap...
>
> How do I update my themes with those updates?

I got following answer for that.

> If I'm not mistaking. You need to put on a pot of coffee, put on your
>   favorite album, and start diffing

What is the meaning of that answer. I have no idea about how that answer related to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *diff* means *compare* (in computing slang), and is normally associated with comparing two text files for differences using the [Unix] `diff` command. However, in your case, I think the respondent meant that you should compare the APIs (programmatic interfaces) of the old and new versions of Understrap. He is also suggesting that you do this whilst drinking some coffee and listening to your favourite music. *Mistaking* should have been *mistaken*, btw. So:

> If I'm not mistaken, you need to drink some coffee, listen to your favourite music, and start comparing the old and new versions of Understrap's API.

Alternatively, he might mean that you should compare the two versions of your theme (using `diff`), looking for calls to the Understrap API.

Note that the `diff` command is used internally by integrated development environments and some version control systems.

Comment: Thanks :-) "you need to drink some coffee, listen to your favourite music"... This means it is not a easy task and you need to relex and use some time,,,,,,," ??????]

Comment: My reading is: It's easy-peasy, so enjoy it.

Comment: I would say you need coffee and tunes because it's incredibly boring, not just easy....

Comment: @ColleenV You may well be right, and I have to admit, that didn't occur to me. I guess it depends on whether you are a nerd or not.